Cartoon with animal characters and medieval elements
The cartoon looked like an 80's or 90's production, and I watched it in the 00's on a Greek TV channel (Acheloos or Art TV). It wasn't a Greek production.
The star was a dog I think with brown-yellowish fur, who was probably a knight or something. He was in love with the princess -- a deer or a gazelle I think. The king was a lion, and everyone wore clothes that had many medieval elements. I recall some similarities with the story of King Arthur (with Excalibur), and I think he had a sword too, maybe with some kind of power? There's a chance his name was actually Arthur, and the whole cartoon had to do with that story. But I'm not sure. 

Welcome to the community. If you know, please also describe the  language, country and year of production, plot locale, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

I think it might be Sylvan (Sylvan, el poder de la magia _ 1995).
Sylvan is a Spanish animated series produced by D'Ocon Films and created by Antoni D'Ocon.
http://1.fwcdn.pl/po/78/94/487894/7636695.5.jpg

Set in the Europe of the Middle Ages, the series details the brave
  adventures of Sylvan, a young rider who has been chosen to defend the
  interests of good and keep evil at bay. Helped by his friends, and the
  magical touch of a wizard, each episode charts his struggle against
  the negative forces that threaten justice and liberty. 

IMDB

The show centers on the character, Sylvan and his heroic fantasy
  adventures in the Middle Ages. Sylvan is a swordsman hero of King
  Charles, who defends and protects the kingdom from the evil forces.

Wikipedia
D'Ocon Films - Sylvan








Sylvan - Youtube

Okay it turns out there was one more with a similar concept that I watched at the same time and obviously mixed stuff up but THAT'S THE ONE THANK YOU I LOVE YOU YOU ARE AWESOME

I'm looking for a similar cartoon (maybe it's this one). Did the lion king throw away the turkey he was eating after just ONE bite and went on to grab another just because he could afford it?
It used to infuriate me as a child.
